# Why would you introduce a constant in a moving average model, when you already have the option of differencing?

Tags: arima, stationarity, moving-average, box-jenkins, differencing

In the online forecasting book of Hyndman (https://otexts.com/fpp2/MA.html) firstly the use of differencing is explained. After that he shows the formula for a moving average model:

$$y_t = c + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \theta_2 \varepsilon_{t-2} + \ldots + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q}$$

I don't see why to add the constant denoted by 'c' in the upper formula. **Is there any difference between introducing 'c' and using first differencing before trying to fit a MA model?** Furthermore, introducing 'c' would imply that it actually ís allowed to have a nonstationary time series. It seems like I'm making a mistake in my thinking...

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent.

If you difference an invertible MA and fit another MA, the differenced population model is not invertible (this is *overdifferencing*).

The first most obvious issue is if you try to fit an MA of the same order you started with you get a different model. Consider an MA(1):

$$y_t = c + \epsilon_t + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}$$

and its first difference:

\begin{eqnarray}
y_t - y_{t-1}  &=& c-c + \epsilon_t + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} -  \epsilon_{t-1} - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-2}\\
  &=&  \epsilon_t - (1-\theta_1) \epsilon_{t-1}  - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-2}
\end{eqnarray}

Well it got rid of the $c$ but it's no longer an MA(1). So we immediately see the differenced model is not equivalent to the model with a constant.

It looks like an MA(2) with the two parameters related. But it's no longer invertible; it has a root on the unit circle. In this case the algebra to see it is straightforward, but I'm going to show you the observed effect on the inverse characteristic roots for a simulated series (since that's something you could do with real data that might help you notice you have overdifferenced).

First I generated 109 observations from an MA(1) with $\theta_1= -0.5$ (in your parameterization) and $c=13.1$, and $\sigma=1$ by hand (this is two short lines in R).

Then using Rob Hyndman's code [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arma-roots/) I generated a plot of the inverse roots for an MA(1) fitted to the y, and an MA(1) fitted to the differenced y (since that's what we'd do if we naively assumed we'd only got rid of the constant without changing anything else), and then an MA(2) fitted to the differenced y (which is what we'd do if we did the above algebra and noticed it looked like an MA(2)).

[image: inverse characteristic roots for MA(1), MA(1) on differenced series and MA(2) on differenced series. Points are at 0.5, at 1 and at 0.5 & 1 respectively]

We can see in both plots for the differenced series - whether we fitted an MA(1) or an MA(2) that there's a root on (or extremely close to) the unit circle. This makes it clear that we fundamentally changed the characteristics of the model by differencing an already stationary-and-invertible series.

Having a constant $c$ doesn't make the series nonstationary. If you start with a stationary series, you don't want to difference it.

---

The R code I used (after running the code to define the functions on Rob's page at the link above):

```
 eps <- rnorm(110)
 y <- 13.1 + eps[2:110] -.5*eps[1:109]
 par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 plot(maroots(Arima(y,c(0,0,1))))
 plot(maroots(Arima(diff(y),c(0,0,1))))
 plot(maroots(Arima(diff(y),c(0,0,2))))
 # don't forget to set the mfrow parameter back
```